# How can I pass an XPath expression in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

As I have an XML file and need to extract the data via [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). But I don't know how to pass an XPath expression via Python to get the data from the XML file I downloaded.

How can we generate the XPath expression by passing the tag name in Python?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree

Comment: Re *"extract the data"*: What kind of extraction? For instance, you could provide an example. Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73918967/edit), not here in comments (but ****** ***without*** ***** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).